# LibreOffice seems to be broken

Tags: icons, libreoffice

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 today only. After the upgrade, it seems like LibreOffice is broken. Icons are not visible.
I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 and LibreOffice Version 6.0.7.3
[image: Writer]
[image: Impress]

**Edit 1:-** Output of `dpkg -l | grep libreoffice | grep -E "icon|style"`
[image: Output]

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep libreoffice | grep -E "icon|style"` to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is solved. I had accidentally deleted some important packages using synaptic. I was trying to free up some space on disk and deleted font files and few other packages. After that, GNOME broke completely!! I was not able to enter the GNOME Desktop Environment. So, I reinstalled GNOME using the following commands.

Delete currently installed GNOME DE:-
`sudo apt-get purge gnome-session gnome-shell gdm3`

Reinstall GNOME DE:-
`sudo apt-get install gnome-session gnome-shell gdm3`